# How can I use raw-loader in vue, and file-loader in scss

Tags: javascript, vue.js, webpack, sass

I want webpack to load differently files in vue html template, and in scss.

```
<template>
  <!-- I want here to load it as inline svg -->
  <div v-html="require('./file.svg').default"></div>
</template>

<style lang="scss">
  .class {
    // but here I wan't to just get rewrite url to loaded file
    background: url('../file.svg'); 
  }
</style>
```

I have this config in webpack, which is applying to both scss and vue files

```
rules: [
  {
     test: /\.svg$/i,
     loader: 'file-loader'
  }
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wasn't able to resolve this issue, so I found ugly workaround. I kept file-loader for everything, but in Vue html template I directly specify to use raw-loader

```
<template>
  <div v-html="require('!raw-loader!./file.svg').default"></div>
</template>
```